# Sum of a complex series involving $e^{2\pi i/N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am trying to solve this sum of a complex series: $$\sum_{k=1, k≠\alpha}^N\frac{\beta^{(k-1)(\lambda-1)}}{\beta^{\alpha-k}-1}$$ where $\alpha,\lambda\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$, and $\beta:=e^{{2\pi i}/N}$. It should turn out to be equal to $$\frac{N+1-2\lambda}{2}\beta^{(\alpha-1)(\lambda-1)}.$$

What I tried was to rewrite each term of the series, because it turns out $$\frac{1}{\beta^{\alpha-k}-1}=-\frac12-\frac{i\sin({2\pi (\alpha-k)}/{N})}{2-2\cos({2\pi (\alpha-k)}/{N})}.$$ This allows for the easy calculation of one part of the sum because $$\sum_{k=1}^N-\frac12\beta^{(k-1)(\lambda-1)}$$ is obviously a geometric sum. But I dont know what to do with the other portion. Any ideas?

Comment: Since, for every $\alpha$, the complex numbers $\beta^{k-\alpha}$ span the set $\{\omega\mid\omega^N=1\ne\omega\}$ of $N$th roots of unity except $1$, the sum is $$\beta^{(\alpha-1)(\lambda-1)}\sum_{\omega\ne1}\frac{\omega^{\lambda-1}}{\omega^{-1}-1}=\beta^{(\alpha-1)(\lambda-1)}\sum_{\omega\ne1}\frac{\omega^{\lambda}}{1-\omega}.$$ Can you continue?

Comment: Hmm yeah from that point on the sum is easy to calculate, but how exactly did you conclude that the sum takes this form just from the observation about $\beta^{k-\alpha}$?

Comment: As I said: by the change of variable $\omega=\beta^{k-\alpha}$.

Comment: Ah okay yeah that makes sense. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: If you reached a complete solution, you might want to post it as an answer below (which, after a while, you could accept).

Comment: Not as easy as I thought at first but will do once i got it